# Can Deduction Guide have an explicit(bool) specifier?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Multiple parts of the standard indicate that deduction guide cannot have an [*explicit-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.spec#nt:explicit-specifier) but can only have an explicit keyword preceding it.

like:

in [temp.deduct.duide](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide#1)

> deduction-guide:
>
> explicit<sub>opt</sub> *template-name* ( *parameter-declaration-clause* ) -> *simple-template-id* ;

note that the standard says : explicit<sub>opt</sub> and not [*explicit-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.spec#nt:explicit-specifier).

or in [dcl.fct.spec](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.spec#3)

> An [*explicit-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.spec#nt:explicit-specifier) shall be used only in the declaration of a constructor or conversion function within its class definition; ...

but the standard also says in [over.match.class.deduct](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#2)

> If the function or function template was generated from a constructor or [*deduction-guide*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide#nt:deduction-guide) that had an [*explicit-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.spec#nt:explicit-specifier), each such notional constructor is considered to have that same [*explicit-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.spec#nt:explicit-specifier).

this quote implies that deduction-guides can have an [*explicit-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.spec#nt:explicit-specifier).

I do not see any particular reason why deduction guide couldn't have a [*explicit-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.spec#nt:explicit-specifier).

Is the issue in my understanding of the standard or in the standard itself ?

Can Deduction Guide have an [explicit(bool)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0892r2.html) specifier ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> I do not see any particular reason why deduction guide couldn't have a *explicit-specifier*.

Me neither. Seems like a total oversight on my part (I'm one of the authors of [conditional `explicit`](https://wg21.link/p0892)). I'll try to file a core issue.

**Update:** This was fixed in [P1968](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1968r0.html#2422), adopted in Belfast, as part of the resolution for core issue 2422.

Comment: For those who are curious: the issue is [CWG2422 Incorrect grammar for deduction-guide](https://github.com/Eelis/draft/commit/7c9d35da990bcd917ce6a25a08f6a629b346ccfe) and it has been resolved.  (Can't find the link though; wg21.link gives 404)

Comment: @L.F.: The public issues list is out of date.  When it gets updated, wg21.link will work for such recent issues.